# Pandas read.csv no separa por columnas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, read

tengo un archivo en csv que tiene 19 columnas, las cual pandas reconoce, pero al leer agrega toda la información es solo la primera columna

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'Path', sep=",", error_bad_lines=False)
```

```
                                                    id  titulo  title  year  \
0    tt6723592,Tenet,,24 September 2020 (Chile),"['...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
1    tt4566758,Mulan,,4 September 2020 (Chile),"['A...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
2    tt0087538,The Karate Kid,,22 June 1984 (USA),"...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
3    tt0087182,Duna,Dune (original title),14 Decemb...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
4    tt4682266,The New Mutants,,28 August 2020 (USA...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
..                                                 ...     ...    ...   ...   
688  tt0287978,Daredevil,,10 April 2003 (Chile),"['...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
689  tt2304933,La quinta ola,The 5th Wave (original...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
690  tt1899353,La Redada,Serbuan maut (original tit...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
691  tt0057193,It's a Mad Mad Mad Mad World,,3 Dece...     NaN    NaN   NaN   
692  tt0244244,Swordfish: Acceso autorizado,Swordfi...     NaN    NaN   NaN
```

```
     genres  director  writers  actors  country  duration  rating  sumprob  \
0       NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
1       NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
2       NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
3       NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
4       NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
..      ...       ...      ...     ...      ...       ...     ...      ...   
688     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
689     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
690     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
691     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN   
692     NaN       NaN      NaN     NaN      NaN       NaN     NaN      NaN
```

```
     prob  sumprob_df  prob_df  sumprob_dt  prob_dt  sumprob_dm  prob_dm;  
0     NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN       NaN  
1     NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN       NaN  
2     NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN      NaN         NaN       NaN
```

Comment: he descubierto que el error surge con los archivos que he modificado manualmente, es decir si elimine o agregue datos (filas). Pero aun no he podido solucionar como hacer la correcta lectura

Answer (score 1):

No podemos ver de ayudarte a solucionarlo al 100 sin un ejemplo. Solo vemos una pequeña parte de lo que podría contener el csv pero realmente tiene muchísimas columnas. Lo mejor en estos casos es añadir un ejemplo de al menos una fila del csv completa para poder pasarlo a código.

Te daré un ejemplo pequeño en base a lo que veo en la pregunta.

Suponiendo que tu `csv` esté compuesto de la siguiente forma:

```
tt6723592,Tenet,,24 September 2020 (Chile)
tt0087538,The Karate Kid,,22 June 1984 (USA)
tt0287978,Daredevil,,10 April 2003 (Chile)
tt4682266,The New Mutants,,28 August 2020 (USA)
```

**Código**:

```
import pandas as pd

fichero_csv = 'data_ejemplo.csv'

nombre_columnas = ['indice', 'código', 'vacia', 'fecha-sitio']

df = pd.read_csv(fichero_csv, sep=",", error_bad_lines=False, names = nombre_columnas)

print(df)
```

Con definir el nombre de las columnas (`name = nombre_columnas`) que va a procesar al leer el `csv`, debe asignarte cada columna al nombre que le has colocado en `nombre_columnas`. Si imprimo el contenido del dataframe, será el siguiente:

```
      indice           código  vacia                fecha-sitio
0  tt6723592            Tenet    NaN  24 September 2020 (Chile)
1  tt0087538   The Karate Kid    NaN         22 June 1984 (USA)
2  tt0287978        Daredevil    NaN      10 April 2003 (Chile)
3  tt4682266  The New Mutants    NaN       28 August 2020 (USA)
```

Aún así, si no defines nombre de columnas, no debería haber problema, te debería separar el dataframe por columnas y colocar la primera fila del `csv` como si fuera los nombres y si alguna está vacía aparecer `Unnamed`.

Comment: las columnas estan definidas cuando escribo el archivo, las cuales son:
columns = ['id', 'titulo', 'title', 'year', 'genres', 'description', 'director', 'writers', 'actors','country', 'duration','rating', 'sumprob', 'prob', 'sumprob_df', 'prob_df', 'sumprob_dt', 'prob_dt', 'sumprob_dm', 'prob_dm']

ahora al nombrar las columnas antes de hacer el 'read', solo me duplica el nombre de las columnas, un dato extra que no agregue es que con una menor cantidad de datos la lectura era correcta, pero cuando ya llegue a un numero superior a 600, paso este error.

Answer (score -1):

Por si alguien llega a este mismo hilo, dejo la solución que a mi me funcionó

data = pd.read_csv('archivo.csv', sep=',')

https://www.analyticslane.com/2020/11/30/pandas-leer-archivos-csv-con-diferentes-delimitadores-en-pandas/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/352744)